# Concatenate Two Cells in Excel Using Python Openpyxl And For loop

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, iteration, openpyxl

I want to concatenate two cells in excel by using openpyxl . But i am struggling to get the code right in "for loop",as i have to iterate and concat the cells .Here's my code so far

```
import openpyxl
wk=openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Uarch\\ConcatDemo.xlsx")
sh=wk['Sheet1']
rows=sh.max_row
columns=sh.max_column
for row_num in range(1,rows+1):
    sh['C{}'.format(row_num)] = '=CONCATENATE(A{},",",B{})'.format(row_num)


wk.save(r"C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Uarch\\ConcatDemo.xlsx")
```

I am getting

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Erro Screenshot:

[image]

Not sure which part is going wrong or i have put a wrong logic.

Input:

[image]

Intended Output:

[image]

Looking forward for help in this..

Comment: `rows+1` is the cause of the error

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat ,Thanks for quick response,but putting only `rows` also causing the same error

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Please share the entire error message, data, etc., and not as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @AMC , Thanks for the info, i have noted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your string formatting in in this section is expecting 2 values rather than 1 in the concatenate function.

```
'=CONCATENATE(A{},",",B{})'.format(row_num)
```

I could achieve your desired behaviour with this

```
import openpyxl
wk=openpyxl.load_workbook("path_to_file.xlsx")
sh=wk['Sheet1']
rows=sh.max_row
columns=sh.max_column
for row_num in range(1,rows+1):
    sh['C{}'.format(row_num)] = '=CONCATENATE(A{},",",B{})'.format(row_num,row_num)
wk.save('file_output.xlsx')
```

To isolate the error

```
'A{}B{}'.format(1)
#IndexError       

'A{}B{}'.format(1, 1)
'A1B1'
```

This can also be done using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel("path_to_file.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="Sheet1")
file[3] = file[0] + ',' + file[1]
file.to_excel("output_file2.xlsx", index=False, header=False)
```